# create dynamic object from dynamic table input text box in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a table which has dynamic rows of input text boxes. Need to save these dynamic textbox values to an object.

textbox names and values are below :
first_textbox : names : name1, name2, name3....etc
second_texbox : school1, school2,school3.. etc...
third_textbox : branch1, branch2,.... etc

```
var n = 10;
var myObject = {};

for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
  var saveName = "name"+i;
  var saveSchool = "School"+i;
  var saveBranch = "branch"+i;

  var saveName = document.getElementById("saveName").value;
  var saveSchool = document.getElementById("saveSchool").value;
  var saveBranch = document.getElementById("saveBranch").value;
  myObject { Name: saveName, School: saveSchool, Branch: saveBranch);
}
```

so at the end the myObject should have 10Names, 10Schools, 10Branches....

Could anyone give me a suggection?

Comment: Do you mean array of objects? like [{}, {}, {}...]

Comment: it's fine to have array of objects too.

Comment: Can you confirm? you want to create dynamic objects using these many textboxes http://jsfiddle.net/93x7y60g/

Comment: <div>  <table>  <tr>
  <td> Name1<input type="text" id = "name1"> </td>
  <td> school11<input type="text" id = "school1"> </td>
 <td> branch1<input type="text" id = "branch1"> </td>  </tr>
 <tr>    <td> Name2<input type="text" id = "name2"> </td>
        <td> school2<input type="text" id = "school2"> </td>
    <td> branch2<input type="text" id = "branch2"> </td>
  </tr>  <tr>  <td> Name3<input type="text" id = "name3"> </td>
        <td> school13<input type="text" id = "school3"> </td>
    <td> branch3<input type="text" id = "branch3"> </td>
  </tr>  </table></div>

Comment: I've posted one answer, please check once whether that one solved your issue or not?

Comment: Thank you so much...  It works as per array of objects... Is there a possible to create one object having elements like name1:name1, name2:name2.. school1:school1, branch1:branch2 etc... 
because in my project I have many objects and need to concatenate... if this table gives one object, that would be easy to combine with my other objects... thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178550/discussion-between-javascript-lover-skt-and-user3280899).

Comment: I've updated my answer as per your requirement, now you can gather the data in single object. Check the updated answer once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your following HTML code given in comments, you can do like below

```js
var result = [];

function storeResult() {
  var noOfRows = document.querySelector('tbody').children.length;
  for (var i = 1; i <= noOfRows; i++) {
    result.push({
      name: document.getElementById('name' + i).value,
      school: document.getElementById('school' + i).value,
      branch: document.getElementById('branch' + i).value
    });
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> Name1<input type="text" id="name1"> </td>
      <td> school11<input type="text" id="school1"> </td>
      <td> branch1<input type="text" id="branch1"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Name2<input type="text" id="name2"> </td>
      <td> school2<input type="text" id="school2"> </td>
      <td> branch2<input type="text" id="branch2"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Name3<input type="text" id="name3"> </td>
      <td> school13<input type="text" id="school3"> </td>
      <td> branch3<input type="text" id="branch3"> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button onclick="storeResult()">Store Result</button>
```

**Update**

As **AmmoPT** said, you can do like below to gather data in single object

```js
var singleObj = {};

function storeResult() {
  var noOfRows = document.querySelector('tbody').children.length;
  for (var i = 1; i <= noOfRows; i++) {
    singleObj['name' + i] = document.getElementById('name' + i).value,
    singleObj['school' + i] = document.getElementById('school' + i).value,
    singleObj['branch' + i] = document.getElementById('branch' + i).value
  }
  console.log(singleObj);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> Name1<input type="text" id="name1"> </td>
      <td> school11<input type="text" id="school1"> </td>
      <td> branch1<input type="text" id="branch1"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Name2<input type="text" id="name2"> </td>
      <td> school2<input type="text" id="school2"> </td>
      <td> branch2<input type="text" id="branch2"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Name3<input type="text" id="name3"> </td>
      <td> school13<input type="text" id="school3"> </td>
      <td> branch3<input type="text" id="branch3"> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button onclick="storeResult()">Store Result</button>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. You are a JavaScript lover! Happy Monday!!

Comment: @user3280899 you're welcome and glad to hear that the answer helpful to you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use bracket notation to add dynamic properties and values to object:

```
myObject { Name: saveName, School: saveSchool, Branch: saveBranch);
```

Becomes

```
var name = 'Name'+i;
var school = 'School'+i;
var branch = 'Branch'+i;
myObject[name] = saveName;
myObject[school] = saveSchool;
myObject[branch] = saveBranch;
```

Also

```
for (i=1; i<n; i++)
```

Should be

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
```

Else `i` will only ever go from 1 to 9, never 10.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. yes, I know it. this is a typo mistake! 

but how do i loop to get the document.getElementById(textboxid).values to the object?

Comment: You already have it in your original code. Replace the line of code I quoted from your original post with the code I gave you. saveName, saveBranch and saveSchool are already defined above, in the loop.